# File Not transferring to server

Tags: php

I have a webpage set up that allows for files to be uploaded, the url of the file is saved in the database that works fine, but the file its self is not getting transferred to the server. I am getting a confirmation of the file be saved and the is saving in the database. 
Here is a copy of my code. 
Any help would be great full.

```
// Start sessions
include('../inc/security.inc.php');
authorise();

// Include databse connection file
include('../inc/connection.inc.php');

// Check to see if the form has been submitted
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// Check to see all fields have been completed
 $target = "../documents/memberDocuments/";
 $target = $target . basename(str_replace(' ','_',$_FILES['documentsURL']['name']));
$documentsURL =(str_replace(' ','_',$_FILES['documentsURL']['name']));
$documentsDescription = $_POST['documentsDescription'];
$lessonID = $_POST['lessonID'];

if (!empty($documentsDescription) && !empty($documentsURL) && !empty($lessonID))    
{
    // Create an SQL query to add the comment
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tblDocuments (documentsDescription, documentsURL, lessonID) VALUES ('$documentsDescription', '$documentsURL', '$lessonID')";

    // Connect to the database
    connect();

    // Run the query and store the result in a variable
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Could not run query");

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['documentsURL']['tmp_name'], $target))

    // Close connection to the database
    mysql_close();

    // Check if query was successful
    if ($result)
    {
        $message = '<div class="success"><p>You have added a new lesson.</p><p>Please <a href="./modules.php">Click Here</a> to view all modules.</p></div>';
    }
    else
    {
        $message = '<div class="error"><p>There was an error adding your record, please try again</p></div>';
    }
}
else
{
    $message = '<div class="error"><p>Please make sure you fill all fields in before submitting the form.</p></div>';
}
    }
    ?>



    <?php
if (isset($message))
{
    echo $message;  
}
?>
     <form action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" form enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="documentsDescription" class="text" id="documentsDescription" placeholder="Enter The Lessons Number"></br></br>
    <input type="file" name="documentsURL" class="text" id="documentsURL" placeholder="Enter The Lesson Description"></br></br>
    <input type="text" name="lessonID" class="text" id="lessonID" placeholder="Enter The Module ID Number"></br></br>
    <button type="submit" input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button iconLeft"><i class="email"></i> Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: You never bothered checking if the upload succeeded. `$_FILES` has a `['error']` parameter for a reason. Check it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: `<form action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" form enctype="multipart/form-data">` You have a rouge `form` word between your `method` and `enctype` attributes.

Comment: i am now getting this error.
Warning: move_uploaded_file(../documents/memberDocuments/Project_4_Brief_2(2).doc) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/dsmith/public_html/Project/member/newDocuments.php on line 31

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpSWd2nQ' to '../documents/memberDocuments/Project_4_Brief_2(2).doc' in /home/dsmith/public_html/Project/member/newDocuments.php on line 31

Comment: Change the permissions of your destination file. Like so: http://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4094/